# How to use HTML entity codes instead of character in HTML

Tags: html, html-entities

I'm writing a post about quote characters like curly quotes. I want to be able to print this string `&ldquo;` to demonstrate html entity of this character `“` but when I open the html page it turns to the character itself.

I think this has to do with the default charset of html5 documents set to `UTF-8` but I've seen pages like [this one](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html) using the raw code.

Is there any way to do this in html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you output `&ldquo;` it's converted to HTML entity `"`. So to output it *as-is* you must double encode it: `&amp;ldquo;`